# svg circle not being drawn with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have been trying to do a hello world for svg manipulation using javascript in HTML. I have written the below code and although it generates the correct html, I don't see any output in the browser, nor do I see any error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var svg1 = document.createElement("svg");
svg1.setAttribute("height",200);
svg1.setAttribute("width",500);
document.body.appendChild(svg1);
var circles = document.createElement("circle");
circles.setAttribute("cx",20);
circles.setAttribute("cy",20);
circles.setAttribute("r",20);
svg1.appendChild(circles);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Where am I going wrong? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 33):

SVG elements need to be created with the SVG XML namespace. You can do that using `createElementNS` and using the `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` namespace:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var svg1 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
svg1.setAttribute("height",200);
svg1.setAttribute("width",500);
document.body.appendChild(svg1);
var circles = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
circles.setAttribute("cx",20);
circles.setAttribute("cy",20);
circles.setAttribute("r",20);
svg1.appendChild(circles);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sure thing. Don't forget to click the checkmark left to the answer if it solved your problem.